# sailsjs returns http code 426 when using a host name

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, sails.js, hostname

While using SailsJS locally (using localhost everything works fine) but if I switch to a hostname (127.0.0.1 defined in the hosts file). I get http code **426**.

Here is the error that I get:
[Http 426](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91U7M.png)

Not sure how the usage of websockets are relevant to the host name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the HTTP 426 error code was caused by the default 1337 port already assigned to different process. (in my case it was Razer's rzsdkserver service :) ).

If you are using SailsJS locally AND using a Razer mouse, make sure you update the default port of SailsJS :https://blog.sailscasts.com/how-to-specify-a-different-sails-port/